# Ping pong heartbeat in ZMQ

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I've been reading the [ZMQ documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Heartbeating) on heartbeats and read that one should use the ping-pong approach instead the one used for the Paranoid Pirate pattern

> For Paranoid Pirate, we chose the second approach. It might not have
>   been the simplest option: if designing this today, I'd probably try a
>   ping-pong approach instead.

However, I find little to no documentation about the ping-pong pattern anywhere (and why is it preferred anyway?). The only possible code examples are [ping.py](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/heartbeat/ping.py) and [pong.py](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/heartbeat/pong.py) in the pyzmq examples.

Are these adequate examples that demonstrate a two-way heartbeat? If so, how is "pong" detecting that "ping" is not alive any more? There's also this claim about no payload, but isn't the [ping message](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/heartbeat/ping.py#L32) also considered a payload?

> One peer sends a ping command to the other, which replies with a pong
>   command. Neither command has any payload

Again, these examples may not constitute a full implementation of this approach. If anyone can share some experience, descriptions or code examples, I'd appreciate it.

My aim is to add heartbeat functionality to a broker and worker (router-dealer). Both worker and broker should detect that the partner isn't available any more and (a) deregister the worker (in case of the broker detecting the worker has gone), or (b) try to reconnect later (in case the worker lost its connection to the broker). The worker isn't required when busy, because it wouldn't be in the broker's idle workers queue for new jobs anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZeroMQ does not provide any mechanism to help you find out whether the socket on the other side is alive or not.
Therefore, the standard scenario of the heartbeat pattern (it is the most convenient I think) is a heartbeat with timeout.

You need sockets on the client and server, which work in separate threads. And also a poller.

Poller example:

```
p = zmq.Poller()
p.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
```

Сlient sends a message to the server and polls the socket with timeout. Choose timeout value that most suits you and will clearly indicate that the server is not available.

Polling example:

```
msg = dict(p.poll(timeout)) 
if socket in msg and msg[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
   # we get heartbeat from server
else:
   # timeout - server unavailable
```

Server does the same.

I think this could help.

Comment: Is this what is "described" as the ping-pong approach in the docs? If so, what is the payload of the message?

Comment: It is not from docs, it is common usage. All we have in docs about ping-pong is general description and you can implement it as needed based on your tasks. Usually if you have 2 servers you don't need any payload, cause all you have to know is the fact of the msg is received. But you may put in msg everything you want, for example server id.

Comment: What if the server becomes unavailable and the client tries to reconnect? Does the client need to tear down the connection and re-initiate it or is this handled by ZMQ?

Comment: @orange If it is REQ-REP pair, and socket didn't get a response, you need to close it and reconnect, cause REQ socket can't send two messages in a row. In another cases, for example if you're using ROUTER and send messages by ID, it can lose routs. All depends on what sockets you chose. In common cases my advice is to close and reconnect socket if you get timeout. This operation is expensive but I think that the server should not fall a hundred times a day)))

Comment: It's a router (server) - dealer (client) connection. If I don't have to and this reconnection is managed internally within ZMQ, I think I wouldn't do it manually... Neither IP address nor port change after the reconnect, so why should the route get lost?

Comment: @orange in this situation, I think it wouldn't and you don't need to reconnect sockets. Just in case test it.

Comment: @orange what do you mean when you're saying "why it was working"? You've tested it) You create a client with DEALER socket and a server with ROUTER. Then you send a heartbeat message to server and start to poll for the answer. When you shutdown server, you get timeout on client. When you become alive, the heartbeat messages again normally arrive on both hosts, right? So what's the problem? Use this pattern))

Comment: I wasn't sure why the reconnect worked without a tear down and re-initialisation of the connection and whether this is the expected behaviour. But I think it is, as ZMQ is dealing with those reconnection things internally.

Comment: @DontPanic The "poller" may timeout if the server doesn't send anything within the time interval, isn't that so?

Comment: ZeroMQ does provide with you heartbeats as means of detecting whether the socket on the other side is alive or not. Check the ZMQ_HEARTBEAT socket options.